# PWA issue with Angular 7 hosting on gh-pages

Tags: angular, progressive-web-apps

I have created an angular application https://github.com/tavishaggarwal/Profiler/tree/dev
And I have enabled service workers on the application.

When I am testing my website, taking it offline on `http-server` it is working fine with all offline capabilities.

But when I have deployed my website on GitHub pages (https) domain.
https://tavishaggarwal.com/ and I am trying to take my website offline, it is returning me 504 error.

The command I used to build my application:

`ng build --prod --base-href "https://tavishaggarwal.com/"`

When I am looking in the application tab in Chrome Developer Tools, I can see my application is successfully registered in service workers.

Please help me to understand what I am doing wrong here.

Comment: Maybe you need to made some configuration in `ngsw-config.json` file to make it working offline too

Comment: @PardeepJain Couldn't find anything to change there as it is working on a localhost server.

Comment: @TavishAggarwal Did You solved the problem?

Answer (score 0):

I'm in the process of typing up a post about how to do this.
My deploy script looks like this `npx ng build --prod --base-href '/' && echo "<custom-domain.tld>" > dist/<project-name>/CNAME && npx ngh --dir=dist/<project-name>`
Found that everytime you deploy using `ngh` you need to specify the `dist/<project>` folder and also add a `CNAME` file to work with a custom domain.

Answer (score 0):

When you commit by git on you ghpage branch, git change the EOL and the computed hash change between the one processed locally and those files stored on the ghpages...

There is a way (I did not try) =>
[Regenerate content hash in ngsw after build or during deploy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54091937/regenerate-content-hash-in-ngsw-after-build-or-during-deploy)

or publish file directly by the interface  on github

[image]

The latest method works for me.. but is quite annoying.